# Wait on client responses to run code socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I have some code that I am only trying to run when both clients have put in their answers. These are the functions finish and datarequest();.

At the moment I have it where it waits for both responses correctly and doesn't emit  just after one client answering. The problem comes in is that it is not reaching my if statement.

Is there a way to ++ nrecieved++; based on the type of answers the clients give. ie. Two wrong answers, two correct answers or one of each? Basically to get it to run nrecieved++; based on both client responses together?

```
var nrecieved = 0;
var responses = {}; // Socket id to response

function finish(){
   // Loop through users in game and send them their responses
   for(var id in responses){
        if(responses.hasOwnProperty(id)){
             // Send the response
             io.to(id).emit('updatePlayer', responses[id]);
        }
   }
}

socket.on('playerCorrect', function (data) {
    nrecieved++;
    responses[socket.id] = data;
    answerValidation(nrecieved);
});    

socket.on('playerWrong', function (data) {
    nrecieved++;
    responses[socket.id] = data;
    answerValidation(nrecieved);
}); 

console.log(nrecieved);
function answerValidation(value) {
    nrecieved = value + value;
    console.log(value);
    if(nrecieved == 2){
        finish();
        dataRequest();
    } 
}
```

EDIT:

Included pastebin: http://pastebin.com/y6akQ6Sh

Client Side:

```
// On click of a answer button check if it is the correct answer if it is tell the server
$(document).on('click', '.answerButton' , function(){

    function answerChecker(element){
        if(element == gaPosition) {
            correctAnswer();
        }
        else {
            console.log("Incorrect!");
            incorrectAnswer();
        }
    }

    var clickedButton = $(this).data('button');
    console.log(clickedButton);
    answerChecker(clickedButton);

}); 

function buttonRemover() {
    $(".buttonContainer").removeClass("fadeInRightBig");
    $(".buttonContainer").addClass("fadeOutRightBig");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".buttonContainer").remove(); 
    }, 500);
}

// Random number function    
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

// Check if correct + send to server
function correctAnswer() {
    var correct = true;
    socket.emit('playerCorrect', {answer: correct});
    console.log(correct);
    buttonRemover();
}

// Check if wrong + send to server
function incorrectAnswer () {
    var wrong   = false;
    socket.emit('playerWrong', {answer: wrong});
    buttonRemover();
}

socket.on ('updatePlayer', function (data) {
    if (data.answer === true) {
        console.log ('Player got it right! ' + data.answer);
    }else if (data.answer === false) {
        console.log ('Player got it wrong! ' + data.answer);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your own object storing the users along with their sockets and their answers.

here is an example of how your storage could be :

```
var socketStorage = {
  roomname : {

   some-socketid : {  // the socket id from socket.id

       username : "username",     // the username of the user
       socket : socket,       // the socket of the user
       currQuestion : {     // an object representing the current question
          answered : false,
          answer : false 
       },
       allQuestionsAnswers : [ true, true, true ] // an array of answers

   },

   some-socketid : {  
    // the socket id from socket.id
       username : "otherusername",     
       socket : socket,      
       currQuestion : {   
          answered : false,
          answer : false 
       },
       allQuestionsAnswers : [ true, true, false ] 

   },

  }
};
```

Here is how u could use this object :

```
var socketStorage = {};

io.sockets.on("connection",function(socket){

 var roomName = "gamelobby"; // ideally generate a unique room where 2    sockets would join


 socketStorage[roomName] = {};

 socketStorage[roomName][socket.id] = {
      username : "username",     
      socket : socket,      
      currQuestion : {   
              answered : false,
              answer : false 
      },
      allQuestionsAnswers : [] 
 };


})
```

Ideally let the user send you his information (such as username), like this for example :

```
 socket.emit("setusername", {username:"my-awesome-username"});
```

and set the username in the storage this way on the server :

```
socket.on("setusername", function(msg){


  socketStorage[roomName][socket.id].username = msg.usename;

})
```

Here is a simple working example :

Client side :

```
socket.on("connect",function(){

    // Joining the game
    socket.emit('joingame', {username:"foobar"});

    $(document).on('click', '.answerButton' , function(){

    function answerChecker(element){
      if(element == gaPosition) {
        correctAnswer();
      }
      else {
        console.log("Incorrect!");
        incorrectAnswer();
      }
    }

    var clickedButton = $(this).data('button');
    console.log(clickedButton);
    answerChecker(clickedButton);

   }); 

  function correctAnswer() {
    var correct = true;
    socket.emit('playercorrect', {answer: true});
    console.log(correct);
    buttonRemover();
  }

  // Check if wrong + send to server
  function incorrectAnswer () {
    var wrong   = false;
    socket.emit('playerwrong', {answer: false});
    buttonRemover();
  }

    socket.on("updateplayer", function(data){
        if (data.answer === true) {
         console.log ('Player got it right! ' + data.answer);
        } else if (data.answer === false) {
         console.log ('Player got it wrong! ' + data.answer);
        }
    })

   socket.on("gamefinished", function(data){
      console.log(data.message);
   });


})
```

And the server side :

```
var users =  {}, validQuestions = [], validCurrQuestion = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on("joingame", function(msg){

            console.log("joining game");

            users[socket.id] = {responses:[],currQuestion: {answered:false,answer:null}};

            socket.on("playercorrect",function(msg){

                users[socket.id].currQuestion.answered = true:
                users[socket.id].currQuestion.answer = true: 
                users[socket.id].responses.push(msg.answer);

                checkAnswers(socket);
            })

            socket.on("playerwrong",function(msg){

                users[socket.id].currQuestion.answered = true:
                users[socket.id].currQuestion.answer = false: 
                users[socket.id].responses.push(msg.answer);

                checkAnswers(socket);
            })


    })


})

io.sockets.on('disconnect', function(socket){
    delete users[socket.id];
})




function checkAnswers(socket){

      var connectedC = Object.keys(users).length;

       for (var clientK in users) {

           // check if current q has been answered

           if(users[clientK].currQuestion.answered) {
            validCurrQuestion.push({socket:socket,answer:users[clientK].currQuestion.answer});

              if (validCurrQuestion.length === connectedC) {
                  // curr question answered by both clients
                  // send result to both
                  sendCurrQresults();

              }

           }

           // if the 8 questions have been answered
           // push into array
           if (users[clientK].responses.length === 8) {
            validQuestions.push(socket.id);
           } 

           // if all users have answered all question send game results
           if (validQuestions.length === connectedC) {
            // finish the game
            getWinner()
           }

       }

}

function sendCurrQresults(){

  validCurrQuestion.forEach(function(question, index){
    question.socket.emit("updateplayer", {answer: question.answer});

    // reset curr question to go to next question
    validCurrQuestion.splice(index, 1);
    users[socket.id].currQuestion = { answered: false, answer: null};

  })

}

function getWinner(){

    // Check who has more true response and send by counting user.responses true vs false

}
```

Comment: I have updated my logic to what you have recommended. But it doesnt seem to be firing off. I have included a pastebin with my main server side folder with its implementation.

Comment: Im on a phone not easy to type code. I have updated my answer to show how to compare if valid number responses equal number of connected users

Comment: Basically store the connected users and their responses and check if the number of responses for each user is equal to the number of responses you expect. If so update an array and compare the length of this array to the length of connected users. I will put a working code when I'm back home. I'm at the restaurant at the moment ;)

Comment: Would be much appreciated. Will give it a try. very new to all of this stuff. As I still want to be able to run this each time a user does something. So all very weird to me.

Comment: Don't worry you will get it working ;) perseverance is the key. I'll update answer in an hour or so. Sorry for the delay

Comment: What data exactly are you emitting to "playerCorrect" and "playerWrong" from the client ?

Comment: I have added client side code. I am basically checking if the button they clicked is correct. If it is I want to tell the server that it is and add 5 points to their score. And if its wrong -3 and then send those values back while calling the datarequest() function which is calling data from an imdb api. Then this would happen 8 times and at the end it will say who won. That is the game outline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116298/discussion-between-factor-za-and-francois-p).